# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. React-Native-Cli setup in android

Tags: react-native-cli

After setup  of react-native-cli and I have the run the app .I am getting this

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:C:\Users\Pallavi\React\Redux\android\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:14: AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.GFGPagination (aka com.redux:style/Theme.GFGPagination) not found.

Comment: I have done that

Comment: How have you done?

Answer (score 0):

```
cd android //Navigate into the android folder from the root directory
./gradlew clean // Run this
```